# Apache created files and its permissions for CentOS 6.x

Tags: files, permissions, directory, apache-httpd, umask

In short, I have an authenticated HTTP-POST that:

- posts a jpg image (created as 666 apache:www) into `/directory1` (777 `ftpuser:www`)
- creates `/directory2` (created as 666 apache:www) in a 777 `ftpuser:www` dir
- moves image into `/directory2` (fails)

All of `/var/www/website.com` is `ftpuser:www` with the exception of Apache-created files of course.

Currently, the image is uploaded as 666 `apache:www`, the folder is created, but the next step of copying the photo fails. Where am I going wrong? I've tried `setpacl` on the apache user and `umask` but I'm spinning my wheels now.

1. Why is it that the apache user can't copy a file it created to a folder it created?
2. `apache` and `ftpuser` are both part of the `www` group. is this bad practice; what's the recommended practice?

Other notes: I'm using `vsftpd` for FTP and using a umask of 002 in my `vsftpd.conf`.

Comment: Do you have selinux running on this system? Use the command `getenforce` to check. Also can you share what is doing the move? Is it a CGI script running on the server or something else?

Comment: It's an third party plugin. Your comment prompted me to find the line that's causing the problem.

https://github.com/philbertphotos/Zenphoto-Lightroom-Publisher/blob/3.02/zp-lightroom/xmlrpc.php#L297

$filename = $args['filename'];
..
..
if (!copy($filename, $filepath.'/'.$filename))
  return new IXR_Error());

Comment: Why don't you write that up as an answer and mark it as the accepted one so this question get's closed out.

Comment: I haven't resolved the issue yet; I'll troubleshoot that line to see if that reveals the underlying issue.

Comment: The `copy()` function is probably going with some alternative permissions, it might be keying off of the `umask` that is set for the apache user.

Comment: Check for  SElinux denial : 

( $ sudo grep denied /var/log/audit/audit.log )

and look if there is something related.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a systemd service on CentOS 7, you need to stop the service and enable it again to have it fixed

```
systemctl stop httpd

vi /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service 
# add this
[Service]
UMask=0002
# safe the file with esc ZZ

# enable and start apache again
systemctl enable httpd
systemctl start httpd
```

Then the funny part is that I have chmod 774 and not 770 mmm

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 apache apache  405163 Apr 26 11:04 0FreeRADIUS.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 apache apache   42496 Apr 26 11:05 admiraliteitsraad.doc
```

Comment: You should not change systemd file located in /usr/lib/systemd, but instead, first disable service then copy the file to /etc/systemd/system and finally re-enable it with the right file.
Next, make your change and reload with systemctl daemon-reload

Comment: centos 6.x doesn't have systemd...